# C++ templates with derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, derived-class, polymorphism

I'm writing a library, and in it I have a class BaseClass.  Anyone using the library will be creating their own classes that inherit from BaseClass.  I have another class, lets call it Manager, which holds a vector of BaseClass pointers, which can hold any object derived from BaseClass.

The Manager class MUST handle the creation and destruction of any object added to its BaseClass vector.  This is because any object in the vector can be deleted at any time, and the Manager itself can also be deleted.  Because of this, the user of the library cannot add an object to the Manager's baseClass vector by passing it a pointer to an already existing object derived from BaseClass.  Well actually, I could allow the user to do that.  But that would involve copying a dummy object, which I'd rather not do.

To solve this, I'm trying to use a template function.  The user should pass the type of the object derived from BaseClass when trying to add it to the Manager's vector.  This is what I currently have.

```
//Manager.h
#include <vector>
#include "BaseClass.h"
#include <typeinfo>

class Manager {
    //Vector holding pointers to any objects inherited from BaseClass
    vector<BaseClass*> baseClasses;

    //Template function that needs to add NEW object to baseClass vector
    //This I'm having problems with
    template<class T>
    BaseClass* Add() {
        BaseClass* baseClass = new T();
        baseClasses.push_back(baseClass);
        return baseClass;
    }

    //Template function that gets object from baseClass vector
    //This works fine
    template<class T>
    BaseClass* Get() {
        for (int i = 0; i < baseClasses.size(); i++) {
            if (typeid(*baseClasses[i]) == typeid(T)) {
                return baseClasses[i];
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }
};
```

For example, the user should do this when adding to or getting an object from the Manager's baseClass vector.  DerivedClass derives from BaseClass

```
Manager manager;
//Add a new DerivedClass object to Manager's vector
manager.Add<DerivedClass>();
//Get a pointer to the DerivedClass object that was just added
DerivedClass* derivedClass = (DerivedClass*)manager.Get<DerivedClass>();
```

My Get() function works fine.  What I need to know is, how can I get my Add() function to work?  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fix the code to reflect what is a member of a type and what not. You should also try to explain a bit further why you think that the manager needs to create the objects, and what exactly you mean by *any object in the vector can be deleted at any time*, who will be doing the deletions? -- what is it that does not work with your `Add` function?

Comment: Which problems are you having with your `Add` function? From your question, I understand that it doesn't work, but i would like to get more details, like does it fail to compile/link? Does it cause a segmentation fault? Does it return a wrong value?

Comment: If you have a pointer to a base class and the base class has a virtual destructor it is safe to delete the object via the pointer.

Comment: @DaleWilson: That depends on many things... for example, if a user gets a pointer and deletes it, then the next `Get` request might crash, so that would not be sufficiently *safe*. But the problem is not well defined, so it is hard to provide a good answer.

Comment: I edited it.  Is that what you wanted?  And my library is a component based game engine.  The Manger class is actually a GameObject, and BaseClass is actually a Component.  The user of the library can create new Components to add to GameObjects.  And to answer who will be doing the deletions... Anything can.  Anything can delete an object, and anything can delete a Component from a GameObject

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas True,  I should have said "just as safe to delete it via the pointer to base class as it would be to delete it via a pointer to the fully derived class."

Comment: Your Get function will not necessarily return a pointer to the object you just added if there is more than one object of the same type in the collection.   Why aren't you using the return value from Add?

Comment: And the problem with my Add() function...  If I do template<BaseClass T> instead, new T() will create an object of type BaseClass instead of the intended derived type.  And template<class T> simply doesn't work because T could be any class, not necessarily of type BaseClass.  Is there a way to make the template enforce that T inherits from BaseClass?

Comment: @JanzDott: So you have a winded question that ends up being: *Can I enforce that a template argument is a type derived from a base?*

Comment: "Do not create god classes/objects in your system. Be very suspicious of a class whose name contains Driver, Manager, System, or Subsystem." --Arthur J. Riel, Object-Oriented Design Heuristics, ISBN 0-321-77496-5.

Comment: @DaleWilson I know, this is just example code.  My actual code has another function where Get() returns an array.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas  Yes, but it was necessary to thoroughly describe my situation.  I found it a little difficult to sum it up into a title for the question

Comment: If DerivedClass is not derived from BaseClass, you will get compiler errors.  And as for "this isn't the actual code."   What kind of answers are you expecting if your example doesn't match the question you are asking?

Comment: @DaleWilson My example does match the question I am asking.  My actual code contains other code which doesn't pertain to the question.  Why would I want to include that?  The code I posted illustrates my problem, and that's all that's needed.  It's easier for everyone who is trying to help me, because there is less to read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are quite a few things unclear about your design, but if the question is whether you can enforce that the type `T` in the member function templa `Add` can be enforced to derive from `BaseClass`, the options are simple:

- do nothing, the compiler will gladly complain on the line `BaseClass* baseClass = new T();`
- add a static assert to make this more obvious
- use fancy SFINAE tricks to remove the function from the set of overloads

I would go for either one of the first two. The static assert could be spelled as:

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of<BaseClass,T>::value);
```

The SFINAE trick, I'd really avoid it, as it it going to make the code more confusing, but could be implemented as:

```
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BaseClass,T>::value,T*>::type
Add() {
   baseClasses.push_back(new T());
   return baseClasses.back();
}
```

(Note that I changed the return type to be `T*`, the object is a `T`, why return a `BaseClass*`? The same applies to the `Get` function there is no point in returning a `BaseClass*`, when you know that the object is really a `T`)

Now the actual problem is far more complicated, since your design is actively avoiding considerations of ownership, which you should not. Think about ownership of the objects and make sure that there is a clear owner (or that the resource is shared). Once you know who owns the objects, create a protocol for the rest of the code to notify the owner when an object needs to be deleted. If you allow *any* code to delete the pointers you hold, you are going to run into undefined behavior very soon.

Other lesser concerns could include the fact that you are enforcing that all components have a default constructor, which might or not be appropriate. You could simplify this restriction by having a non-templated `Add` that takes a pointer, and letting the caller create the objects in the way they please.

The use of `typeid` is usually a code-smell and I don't think this is the exception, maybe you would be better off by designing a type hierarchy that you can ask what the object is, rather than running `typeid`. If you are really determined to make the interface based on types, then consider whether `dynamic_cast` could be better. It will be more innefficient, but if you have multiple levels of inheritance, it will let you return the most derived objects as intermediate objects

Comment: I'm using the static_assert method, and new T() is creating objects of type BaseClass instead of the derived class.  Do you know why this is?  And I knew my design choice would come into question.  But the Manager (or GameObject actually) owns the objects.  But any object can tell the manager to delete them

Comment: @JanzDott: There is a big difference between stating that anyone can delete the object and stating that anyone can ask the manager to remove the object

Comment: Yes I know.  I'm sorry, I misspoke